# using AUTO_INCREMENT on combo keys

Tags: mysql, database

I am using MySQL for a database project, and one of my tables uses combo keys as a PK, entry_ID+user_ID(FK).

This is the table structure:

```
| address_list | CREATE TABLE `address_list` (
  `entry_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `addrs_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `addrs_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_ID`,user_ID),
  KEY `user_Fk` (`user_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_Fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_ID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`user_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

What I am trying to achieve is to auto increment entry_ID for each user separately here's an example of what the table might look like after doing some inserts.

Is there a way to do this with just using MySQL?

```
 user_ID           entry_ID
----------------------------
        1   |    1
        2   |    1
        1   |    2
---------------------------
```

Comment: There is only one option to achieve this without additional (trigger, SP) code. Alter the engine to MyISAM and define PK as `(user_id, entry_id)`. But you will lose table transactionality.

Comment: would it make sense if i just increment entry_ID for each insert into the table without worrying about keeping track of what user_ID should entry_ID be incremented to? As long as the the combo key is unique in the table. Are there any performance drawbacks on this?

Comment: When you use auto_increment field without direct value assign there is no sense in complex PK or even UNIQUE - AI field provided uniqueness itself, and additional field has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use DEFAULT if to be auto_increment upon inserts.

```
INSERT INTO address_list ( address_list.entry_ID, address_list.user_ID, address_list.addrs_1, address_list.city, state, address_list.zip_code, country, phone ) 
VALUES (DEFAULT , 4, '234 Example Ave', 'Las Vegas', 'NV', '23569','USA','987-654-3210');
```

[image: Example]

Hope this is what was asked! if not truly sorry!